# Is it possible to preload/precache data in memory with Couchbase?

Tags: database, caching, memory, preload, couchbase

We have let's say we have 16GB of information, and we could use around 8GB of ram.

This information is divided in subsets. Each of these subsets represents a currency (USD, EUR, etc.). The stored data are just pairs key-value (time_in_ms-currency price) for the last 5 years.

We will have like 80 different currencies, and we know which ones will be mostly requested: USD, EUR, etc. And there will be others that will be rarely requested.

I read something about the warming up in Couchbase, but it seems that it affects to all the data of your database.

Is it possible to preload selectively the data we want (USD, EUR - most popular currencies-) in couchbase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three obvious steps:

- create bucket with 8GB ram quota
- load all you data. in this case you will have rather low "active docs resident ratio %", apparently less than 50%
- once read the mostly used/requested data and couchbase will place it in memory for you. it sounds like manual warmup but it will help. And submillisecond latency is worth doing that. Otherwise your users will do that for you.